# Вопрос по протоколу ARP

Tags: сеть, протоколы, arp

Одно из применений ARP это определение MAC-адреса по известному IP-адресу.

Пакет ARP содержит поля Source IP и Source MAC, и поля Destination IP и Destination MAC (ну и другие, конечно).

Когда идет ARP пакет типа ARP-запрос, то в поле Destination MAC - нули.
Когда идет ARP пакет типа ARP-ответ, заполняется поле Destination MAC и в пакете меняются местами получатель и отправитель.

Но, если в пакете-запроса есть поля SrcIP и SrcMAC, то одна ARP-транзакция (ARP-запрос, ARP-ответ) позволяют двум узлам сразу установить соответствие между IP-адресом и MAC-адресом другого. Т.е. в обеих узлах появится запись в ARP-таблице.

Это всегда так, что при одной ARP-транзакции в обеих узлах появляется запись в ARP-таблице или бывает, что нужно делать еще два ARP-запроса, что бы другой узел создал запись в своей ARP-таблице?

И еще такой вопрос: устройство, к которому подключаются компьютеры локальной сети  (например, маршрутизатор) может делать Broadcast-ARP запрос — он принимается всеми компьютерами в одном сегменте локалки.

Но у меня выходит так,что один из компьютеров локальной сети тоже посылает Broadcast-ARP запрос. Какой тут смысл в Broadcast если этот запрос кроме маршрутизатора никто "не услышит"? Не проще послать Glorious запрос, или просто запрос с Destination MAC = 0.

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто, если MAC-адрес конкретного IP не известен, то шлется широковещательный запрос, потому что мы еще не знаем куда слать. Владелец IP ответит. Абсолютно не важно кто посылает запрос маршрутизатор или любой другой компьютер. Все устройства работают одинаково, понадобился IP такой то (и неважно кто он, наш маршрутизатор или другой хост), этого IP еще нет в кеше - шлем широковещательный запрос.

Большинство современных операционных систем добавляют запись в arp-таблицу только когда получают ответ на *свой* arp-запрос. Во первых броадкаст запросы шлют все устройства в сети, т.е. запрос увидят все. Если кешировать ip-mac со всех пролетающих мимо запросов то таблица будет заполнятся массой не нужной нам информации. Кроме того, существует атака arp-poison (отравление arp кеша). Для нее шлют широковещательные (или unicast) запросы с поддельных MAC-адресов отправителя со случайными IP. Если устройство будет писать к себе все приходящие запросы, то таблица переполнится. По этому чужим запросам верить не принято и будет послан встречный запрос и поверят только ответу.

Если запись IP в таблице уже есть, но достаточно старая и при этом она все еще нужна (с ней идет обмен трафиком) то периодически посылаются проверочные запросы, вот они шлются unicast т.к. MAC назначения известен.

Есть еще особый вид ARP-запросов. Когда машина получила IP (из своих настроек или по DHCP) и включает его на интерфейсе она шлет 3 широковещательных ARP-запроса со своим IP и в Dest и в Src. Это делается для проверки на конфликты IP-адресов в сети. Если такой же IP у кого то в сети уже есть - то он ответит как на обычный запрос и машина или откажется от адреса, полученного по DHCP, или сообщит пользователю о конфликте в случае заданного в ручную (по крайней мере часть ОС так делают)